# Am I not using fseek() properly?

Tags: c, binaryfiles, fseek

I'm trying to update some info in my binary file, but I'm facing a problem while trying to go backward, to the beginning of the line.

```
void updateSalary(char* filename)
{
    int i = 0;
    employee temp;
    char c;
    float increase;
    FILE *fup = fopen(filename, "rb+");
    if (fup == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to read the file\n");
        return;
    }

    fread(&temp, sizeof(employee), 1, fup);
    while (!feof(fup))
    {
    printf("How big is the increase to %s's salary?\n", temp.name);
    scanf("%f", &increase);
    temp.salary += increase;
    fseek(fup, (i * sizeof(employee)), SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(&temp, sizeof(employee), 1, fup);
    fread(&temp, sizeof(employee), 1, fup);
    i++;
    }
fclose(fup);
}
```

The problem is, for instance, if I choose to update 2 employees, for some reason, the while loop doesn't stop at the 2nd employee and the function keep going..

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
it seems that the fwrite(); function didn't advance (by position meaning) til the next line, so there is the fixed code:

```
void updateSalary(char* filename, float threshold)
{
    int i = 0;
    employee temp;
    char c;
    float increase;
    FILE *fup = fopen(filename, "r+b");
    if (fup == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to read the file\n");
        return;
    }
    //fread(&temp, sizeof(employee), 1, fup);
    while (fread(&temp, sizeof(employee), 1, fup))
    {
    printf("How big is the increase to %s's salary?\n", temp.name);
    rewind(stdin);
    scanf("%f", &increase);
    temp.salary += increase;
    fseek(fup, (i * sizeof(employee)), SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(&temp, sizeof(employee), 1, fup);
    **fseek(fup, ((i+1) * sizeof(employee)), SEEK_SET);**
    i++;
    }
fclose(fup);
}
```

Comment: feof probably doesn't work the way you think it does.

Comment: @NickS I read about feof, and I understood that it doesn't check the next char to be EOF, but I also understood that feof returns 0 if there was an attempt to read from an unavailable position of the file.. thats why I placed fread at the end of the loop + outside the loop.. correct me if I'm worng.

Comment: There is no “EOF char.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I didn't say there was any...

Comment: You did say “check the next char to be EOF” which can easily be construed as meaning that there is an “EOF char”.  I’m glad you don’t think there is one, but it wasn’t clear from what you said.

Comment: Anyway guys, I also tried to build a condition based on what fread() returns (instead of !foef), but for some reason, the function doesn't return "0".

Comment: Regardless, you should be testing the return value from `fread()`.  And from `fwrite()`.  And `feof()` is very seldom used except by novice C programmers.  I write a lot of code using standard I/O and in thousands of files written over 30 years, found there were a dozen or so files where I’d used `feof()`, and in none of those was it used in a loop but it was always after a loop had exited and the test distinguished between an error and EOF.

Comment: before writing/updating a value, try your code only to read/print employee list from data with fseek. check if you get the full list without any problem and update your question. if possible give us your epmloyee class/struct and a few data to write and try.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I switched the condition of the while again, now I just placed a constant (i<2), so I could print just 2 employees. the update works and I receive the 2 updated salaries.. but.. there is also a duplicated 3rd data of the "old" last employee. Any suggestions?

Comment: it depends on where you used your condition

Comment: @YılmazDurmaz replaced it with while (!feof(fup))

Comment: in your case, it would be better to use do-while, to cut that rogue 3rd data

Comment: *I choose to update 2 employees, for some reason, the while loop doesn't stop at the 2nd employee and the function keep going*, but your code tries to update until end of file as the while expression states: *!feof(fup)*. Please precise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the fine print in the [`fopen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) documentation:

> In update mode ('+'), both input and output may be performed, but output cannot be followed by input without an intervening call to fflush, fseek, fsetpos or rewind, and input cannot be followed by output without an intervening call to fseek, fsetpos or rewind, unless the input operation encountered end of file.

Reading and writing might be buffered, but still share a single file position. Switching modes without alerting the runtime (using `fseek`) could mess up the buffering.

So the lines

```
fseek(fup, (i * sizeof(employee)), SEEK_SET);
fwrite(&temp, sizeof(employee), 1, fup);
fread(&temp, sizeof(employee), 1, fup);
```

need one more `fseek` between write and read.

Comment: please edit your answer to give a "suggested" code, not " ... bla bla ... needs more ..." expression. That would make it more applausable

Comment: do not reference cppreference, it is a unofficial c++ reference site and question is about c...

Comment: I used fseek(i); for reading and writing, and then manually used fseek(i+1) to point the position to the next structure.